# Access value from model

Tags: json, swift, rest, swiftui

Can Someone please tell me how I can access this value: `var the15X: String` inside the `struct ImgSrcSetClass` ?

This is the model:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Fish: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var url: String
    var imgSrcSet: ImgSrcSetUnion
    var meta: Meta

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, url
        case imgSrcSet = "img_src_set"
        case meta
    }
}

enum ImgSrcSetUnion: Codable {
    case enumeration(ImgSrcSetEnum)
    case imgSrcSetClass(ImgSrcSetClass)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(ImgSrcSetEnum.self) {
            self = .enumeration(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(ImgSrcSetClass.self) {
            self = .imgSrcSetClass(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(ImgSrcSetUnion.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for ImgSrcSetUnion"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .enumeration(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .imgSrcSetClass(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - ImgSrcSetClass
struct ImgSrcSetClass: Codable {
    var the15X: String
    var the2X: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the15X = "1.5x"
        case the2X = "2x"
    }
}

enum ImgSrcSetEnum: String, Codable {
    case notAvailable = "Not available"
}
```

I am able to get for example the name by calling `Text(fish.name)`.
But I don't know how to access the img-URL.

Additionally here is the json schema I'm fetching:

```json
{
    "id": 1097,
    "name": "Waspfish",
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waspfish",
    "img_src_set": {
      "1.5x": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/YamahimeK.jpg/330px-YamahimeK.jpg",
      "2x": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/YamahimeK.jpg/440px-YamahimeK.jpg"
    },
    "meta": {
      "scientific_classification": {
        "kingdom": "animalia",
        "phylum": "chordata",
        "class": "actinopterygii",
        "order": "scorpaeniformes",
        "family": "scorpaenidae",
        "subfamily": "tetraroginaej._l._b._smith,_1949"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you expect to always have `"1.5x"` and optionally `"2x"` in `img_src_set`, or could there be more, e.g. `"2.5x"` etc...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an instance of `Fish` in a variable named `fish`.

```
let fish: Fish = ...
```

You can check the `imgSrcSet` as follows:

```
if case let .imgSrcSetClass(imgSrcSet) = fish.imgSrcSet {
    let the15x = imgSrcSet.the15X
    print(the15x)
}
```

The contents of the `if` will execute if the value of `fish.imgSrcSet` is the enum case `.imgSrcSetClass`. The variable `imgSrcSet` will be set to the associated value of the case. This gives you access to the properties of the `ImgSrcSetClass` value.